# cant use functions on data fetched from async storage because its null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am fetching data from async storage, and then using `filter()` on the data, but I am getting an error that says the data is null.

```
const clearVillager = async (villager) => {
    try {
        let storedVillagers = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@storage_Key');
        JSON.parse(storedVillagers);
        storedVillagers = storedVillagers.filter(obj => {
            return (obj.id !== villager.id)
        });
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('@storage_Key', storedVillagers);
    } catch(e) {
        alert(e);
    }
};
```

```
const villagerArray = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Bob'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Mob'
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Pob'
    }
]
```

Basically I'm getting `storedVillagers` which is an array of objects (each object is a villager), and then im using the `filter` function to remove a villager from the array. Then I want to update the storage with this new array.

[image]

This is the error I'm getting. I know for sure that the line
`let storedVillagers = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@storage_Key');` works. It just seems like when I try to use `filter()`, `storedVillagers` hasn't been fetched yet hence its undefined. I'm not sure how to fix this issue.

Comment: I don't see anything in your question that says anything is `null`. Rather the value `storedVillagers.filter` is `undefined`. This is a different thing altogether.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in `storedVillagers.getItem` is string. After that you have to parse the testing to array, which you are doing. But you have to change the variable too. Just like, assigning `storedVillagers  = JSON.parse(storedVillagers);`

```
const clearVillager = async (villager) => {
    try {
        let storedVillagers = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@storage_Key');
        storedVillagers  = JSON.parse(storedVillagers);
        storedVillagers = storedVillagers.filter(obj => {
            return (obj.id !== villager.id)
        });
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('@storage_Key', storedVillagers);
    } catch(e) {
        alert(e);
    }
};
```

Comment: It will help future visitors more if you explain why this fixes the problem. Also, I suggest using two different variable names for JSON string and the parsed object.